# How to store 10000 record in MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a huge number of records may be 10000 and I need to store them in a MySQL database. I also changed `max_input_vars = 10000` without success. I am using

> PHP 5.6.14

and

> phpMyAdmin 4.5.1

How can I address this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want to load your records ? CSV file ? SQL request ?

Comment: @Vincent Decaux; I want to load SQL request

Comment: do you get any errors? if yes could you please show them?

Comment: 10 thousand is nothing. So what is the problem.

Comment: Whats the error that you have been getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't phpMyAdmin automatically break large queries in parts? I think there was a checkbox somewhere in the import page. Also try zipping your SQL, it'will be uploaded by phpMyAdmin much faster.

Another way is to run the query from command line (ssh) like following:

```
mysql --user=[your db username here]
--password=[your db password here] [your db name here] 
< [your sql file name here]
```

Also don't forget to remove all `[` and `]`.